# Manage printers on Android tablets

Tags: printing

We have a number of Android tablets at my workplace for access to an internal web application. We would like to print from this application from the tablets and have a number of compatible printers on our network.

However every tablet can "see" every printer and the users become confused as to which printer they should print to, sometimes printing to a printer that is not even in the same building let alone near them.

Is there a way of managing the list of printers in Android to restrict (and ideally rename) which printers each tablet can "see"?

Comment: How should an Android device know if printer is next to it or not? Tablets are portable so you can take them anywhere within one of your buildings. Or you could switch to and central print server and activate "secure printing": the print job is automatically routed to the printer where the user which has printed the document authenticates itself (e.g. by NFC or BlueTooth between tablet and printer) - so the printer only starts if you got to the printer and authenticate yourself.

Comment: Sorry, I havn't explained myself very well. I don't expect the tablets to "know!" where which printer to send to, I want to manually specify the printer, i.e. restrict which printer a tablet can print to to just one that has been selected for that tablet. Current behaviour has the tablet showing ALL printers on the network, I would like to reduce this list to only the relevant printers manually selected.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the router and Waps then the easiest way would to put the printers on their own subnet and create a Wifi network on that subnet just for the tablets.  If desktops need to communicate with the tablets, then you can configure the desktops to use two subnets.

Comment: Currently all devices are on the same subnet, a class A 10.x.x.x network. Segregating the tablets into areas is possible, but seems like overkill just for printing.